# Use Xdebug var_dump function without enabling other features

Tags: php, xdebug, xdebug-3

I only use `var_dump` functionality from `xdebug` extension.

I have set php.ini to `xdebug.mode = develop`.

But develop mode slows the whole application (I am assuming it enables a lot more features other than just `var_dump`).

Is it possible to enable only `var_dump` feature and disable all the rest of the features from Xdebug extension?

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible. However, you can set `xdebug.mode=off` and call it as `xdebug_var_dump()` instead.

Comment: `xdebug_var_dump` sounds perfect. Is it possible to override `var_dump` with `xdebug_var_dump` myself in `auto_prepend_file` maybe?

Comment: I don't think so!